# Using R gmp big numbers in a dataframe/tibble and plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gmp, largenumber

I have some computations that involve calculations with very large numbers, and understand that the package gmp allows handling of arbitrarily large numbers. However, if I try to use the numbers in a tibble or plot them, R gives the following errors, even for numbers the size of which R can handle, so I know that the simple size of the number is not the problem:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, unname, value = list(a =
> as.raw(c(0x03,  :    replacement element 1 has 3 rows, need 40

and for plotting:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type bigz.
> Defaulting to continuous. Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or
> the same as the data (40): x

The following reprex should produce the same errors:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gmp)

test <- tibble(a = c(as.bigz("1000000"), as.bigz("1000000"), as.bigz("1000000")))

test <- mutate(test,
               b = a + 50000)
```

I can see that the calculations have in fact worked:

```
test$b
```

But get errors when trying to just look at the tibble or plot the numbers:

```
test

ggplot(data = test) +
  geom_point(aes(x = b, y = 1))
```

I assume the problem is something to do with the class of the bigz, but don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

We can wrap it in a `list`, loop over the `list` and do the transformation

```
library(dplyr)
library(gmp)
library(purrr)
test <- tibble(a = list(as.bigz("1000000"), as.bigz("1000000"), 
        as.bigz("1000000"))) %>% 
     mutate(b = map(a, ~ .x + 50000))
```

-output

```
> test
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  a           b          
  <list>      <list>     
1 <bigz [16]> <bigz [16]>
2 <bigz [16]> <bigz [16]>
3 <bigz [16]> <bigz [16]>
> test$b
[[1]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 1050000

[[2]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 1050000

[[3]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 1050000
```

---

Not sure if `ggplot` can accept the `bigz` vector.  But, the `list` can be converted to a vector and use `plot` from `base R`

```
test <- tibble(a = list(as.bigz("1000000"), as.bigz("1000000"), 
        as.bigz("1000000"))) %>% 
     mutate(b = map2(a, seq(50000, length.out = n(), by = 10000), ~ .x + .y))
plot(do.call(c, test$b), y = rep(1, nrow(test)))
```